# Ocaml: It there a way to pass objects between processes?

Tags: multithreading, ipc, ocaml, pipe

This is a real question.

I am working with named pipes to transmit data between processes/threads, but this data is of type string is is possible to pass and object this way?

Is there anyway to pass an object?

My problem is the following:

I have a thread Missile, and a Process World.
World receives the location of the Missile and returns the computation of the new location.

Right now I am doing this by taking information from the string writing in the pipe. Is there a way to pass this as an object or a tuple?

If anyone could help me with this, it would be great!
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Marshal` module to pass arbitrary OCaml values through a bytestream. It's tricky to get right, so I'd advise reading the [Marshal section of the manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Marshal.html). The main thing is that it only passes values, not types. So your receiving process will need to have a definition for the exact type of the object being passed, and you need to specify the type explicitly in the receiver.

Values that contain functions, which includes OO-style objects, can't be marshalled except between copies of the same program. Maybe this applies to your case (since you mention that you have a thread), but it might be better to use a tuple anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Convert objects to JSON? pass the data between processes as JSON strings?